# geocodePostalAddress - get Address from zip code

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I'm trying to get the address from the postal code, but I'm getting the error and no placemarks. It seems the device cannot find the location. Why is this?

Locale doesn't matter, I tried with and without and the result is same.

```
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

let postalAddress = CNMutablePostalAddress()
postalAddress.postalCode = zipCode

geocoder.geocodePostalAddress(postalAddress, preferredLocale: Locale(identifier: "en_US")) { (placemarks, err) in
        if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {
            completionHandler(placemark)
            return
        }
        completionHandler(nil)
}
```

```
err = (Error?)  domain: "kCLErrorDomain" - code: 8
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clerror/kclerrorgeocodefoundnoresult?language=objc Maybe a zip code alone is too vague?

Comment: Tried this ```postalAddress.isoCountryCode = "US"```, but same

Comment: Try geocodeAddressString instead please.

Comment: @matt I tried but the same result, just noticed it's working on the simulator but not on the device. still finding out the issue.

Comment: Wow really interesting, thanks for experimenting. Is the device doing geocoding at all? Weird.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. @EgorT have you been hammering the geocoder? You get throttled for that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess there's something wrong with your testing procedure or your device, because I can't reproduce the problem. I don't have a completion handler so I changed the code to this:

```
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    let postalAddress = CNMutablePostalAddress()
    postalAddress.postalCode = "93023"
    geocoder.geocodePostalAddress(postalAddress, preferredLocale: Locale(identifier: "en_US")) { (placemarks, err) in
            if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {
                print(placemark)
                return
            }
            print(err)
    }
```

I got

```
93023, Ojai, CA  93023, United States...
```

which is correct. Maybe you've been hammering the geocoder so you got throttled? Or maybe there's some bad setting on your device? Or it could be something more subtle.

Comment: Yes, I guess something wrong with my device. I will follow up when I find something.

Comment: Are you _in_ the US? Maybe there’s some rule about this that we don’t know.

Comment: They work for me too - on device, simulator and (amazingly!) in a playground. I assume you used the same zip on device & simulator?

Comment: Yes, but maybe the device works differently. And that's what's important.

Answer (score 1):

CLGeocoder also works for me, but if its not working for you try this MKLocalSearch Playground instead:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = "93023"
let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
search.start { response, error in
    guard let response = response else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "This should be impossible")
        return
    }
  print(response.mapItems.first?.placemark.title ?? "No Placemarks")
}
```

output:

```
Ojai, CA  93023, United States
```